# Get assemblyname of a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-assembly, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

#### What I need

I want to obtain the assembly name of a Project in an Visual Studio Extension.

Since I know that you can see it when right clicking on a Project in the Solution Explorer and select `Properties`. It will show the `Assemblyname` in the tab `Application`.

#### Setup

I have a "Command" in my extension project which shows when you right click something in the solution explorer. As soon as someone clicks the command the following code will execute:

```cs
var dte = await GetDTE2Async();

await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();

var selectedItem = GetSelectedItem(dte);
var props = selectedItem.ContainingProject.Properties;
//I just assumed that the `AssemblyName` could be somewhere in the `Properties` Property.
```

Where the `GetSelectedItem` method looks like this:

```cs
public static ProjectItem GetSelectedItem(DTE2 dte)
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();
    var items = (Array)dte.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer.SelectedItems;

    return items.Cast<UIHierarchyItem>().FirstOrDefault().Object as ProjectItem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who has the same issue, I actually was pretty close to my goal.

#### How I found it

It was just about guessing, in my case I assumed that the `Properties` is a bunch of `Property` items.

After that I just collected all the key pair values that the `IEnumerable` had. Then saw that there is acutally an Item called `AssemblyName` which indeed matches the correct value.

```cs
var items = selectedItem.ContainingProject.Properties.Cast<Property>()

var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    sb.Append($"Name : {item.Name} ");
    try
    {
        sb.Append("Value : " + item.Value.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        sb.Append("Value : NOT DEFINED (EXCEPTION)");
    }
    finally
    {
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
}
var output = sb.ToString();
```

#### Solution

It is a fairly short part, but here we go:

```cs
var assemblyName = selectedItem.ContainingProject.Properties.Cast<Property>().FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name == "AssemblyName").Value;
```

Basically I am just searching the first element which matches the name `AssemblyName` and get its value.

Comment: Actually there's related info in [Get Project Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-project-properties?view=vs-2019#to-display-project-properties-in-a-tool-window). We can also use a foreach or what to get the Property of AssemblyName in returned [Project.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.project.properties?view=visualstudiosdk-2017).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(Property's Type).FullName
```

Comment: I already tried this, it will result in `System.__ComObject` which is definitely wrong.